# SharePoint 2010 : Unable to open page layout

Tags: sharepoint-designer, page-layout

I having an issue on SharePoint 2010 Designer where the Page Layout was unable to edit, it hit error as below:

**The server could not complete your request. For more specific information, click the Details button.**

Error after click Details

**soap:ServerServer was unable to process request. ---> Cannot complete this action. Please try again. ---> Cannot complete this action. Please try again.0x80004005**

Please help.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a custom page layout, maybe with a custom web part built in? I havent seen this before in a default page layout.

Comment: There is custom user control (.ascx) registered in, the page layout is not create in before the content DB was migrated, any idea how to open it?

Comment: Can you export the layout and open it up in visual studio to remove the custom control and then add the page layout back?